# Find General Solution of First Order DE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find general solution of
>   $$y'+\frac{2y}{x}=\frac{3}{x^2}$$
>   and find solution for which
>   $$y(2)=-1$$
>   I know
>   $$xy'+\frac{r(x)y}{x}=3r(x)x$$
>   $$(ry')=ry'+r'y$$$$r'=\frac{r}{x},\frac{r'}{r}=\frac{1}{x},ln(r)=ln(x),r=x$$$$\frac{xy'}{2}+y=\frac{3}{2x}$$
>   $$\frac{(xy)'}{2}=\frac{3}{2x}$$$$\frac{xy}{2}=\int \frac{3}{x}dx=3ln|x|+c$$
>   but where to from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a non-homogeneous linear ODE and IVP. Find the general solution in two steps:

1) Solve the homogeneous equation:
$$y'+\frac{2y}{x}=0 \Rightarrow\frac{1}{y}dy=-\frac{2}{x}dx \Rightarrow y=\frac{C}{x^2}.$$
2) Assume $y=\frac{C(x)}{x^2}:$
$$y'+\frac{2y}{x}=\frac{3}{x^2} \Rightarrow \frac{C'(x)x^2-2xC(x)}{x^4}+\frac{2C(x)}{x^3}=\frac{3}{x^2} \Rightarrow$$
$$C'(x)=3 \Rightarrow C(x)=3x+A$$
Thus: $y=\frac{C(x)}{x^2}=\frac{3x+A}{x^2}$ is a general solution.

To find a particular solution (that is, the value of the constant $A$), use the initial value $y(2)=-1:$
$$\frac{3\cdot 2+A}{2^2}=-1 \Rightarrow A=-10.$$
Thus: $y=\frac{3x-10}{x^2}$ is a particular solution.

Answer (score 3):

Something is wrong in your procedure. In particular 
$$\frac{xy'}{2}+y\not=\frac{(xy)'}{2}.$$

Note that by multiplying both sides of the ODE by $x^2$, we get
$$x^2 y'+2xy=3$$
and the LHS is the derivative of $x^2 y$. Hence, after integrating,  we obtain the general solution:
$$y(x)=\frac{3x+C}{x^2}.$$ 
Finally, in order to find the constant $C$, use the condition $y(2)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I have an itch to add a proper procedure.

Suppose we have the following first order linear non-homogeneous differential equation!

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2y}{x}=\frac{3}{x^2}$$

By method of inspection we notice that we can use the integrating factor method since this is a linear one!

So,

Generally,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$$

The integrating factor can be found by

$$\mu=e^{\int P(x)dx}$$

So, onto your question

Integrating factor is

$$\mu=e^{\int \frac{2}{x}dx}$$

$$\mu=e^{2ln|x|}$$

$$\mu=e^{ln|x^2|}$$

$$\mu=x^2$$

Multiplying the differential equation with the integrating factor we have,

$$\frac{x^2dy}{dx}+2xy=3$$

So, by it we have

$$\int d(yx^2)=\int 3 dx$$

$$yx^2=3x+C$$

Initial value is $y(2)=-1$

So by it we have

$$C=(-1)(2)^2-3(2)$$

$$C=-10$$

Rewrite the particular solution differential equation

$$yx^2=3x-10$$

Addendum. Some old story for integrating factor!

$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$

Know that if f is the differential equation!

$$M=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},N=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

The differential equation is said to be exact if

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

It is also known as Clairaut's theorem. Which implies continuity of certain function!

Let it be the case where,

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

We multiply the differential equation with integrating factor $\mu(x)$
We assume that $\mu$ depends on one variable only not the other. So, in our case assume it to be dependent on x!

$$\mu(x)Mdy+\mu(x)Ndx=0$$

Applying Clairaut's theorem and assume after some multiplication with integrating factor we have an exact differential equation.

$$\mu$$

$$\frac{\partial \mu(x)(M(x,y))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \mu(x)(N(x,y))}{\partial x}$$

Since $\mu(x)$ is not affected by y then we can write,

$$\mu(x)\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}=\mu(x)\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x}+N(x,y)\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}$$

$$\int\frac{1}{N(x,y)}(\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x})dx=\int\frac{d\mu}{ \mu(x)}$$

$$e^{\int\frac{1}{N(x,y)}(\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x})dx}=\mu$$

It is considered lucky if we can find the integrating factor of the differential equation!